# To lock or not to lock

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutex, semaphore, race-condition

I have a JavaScript/jQuery web app that contains an object that is read/write accessed by the user via DOM events as well as by the server via web sockets or xhr.

I know that JavaScript is single threaded. Nevertheless, I suspect that in this setting the object in question might be subject to race conditions, and I wonder how to deal with this in the absence of locks in JavaScript.

Comment: If you are processing updates to your copy of an object asynchronously over a websocket, then you have to either (a) make sure each update is complete and puts the object in a proper state (i.e., is atomic), or (b) implement transactions (ugh, is there a library for this?), or (c) accept that the local object is in an incorrect state from time to time.

Comment: i don't think i've ever seen a true race condition appear in actual javascript code, though there's a first for everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket will write via events just like the user would. Events will get queued no matter what the source is. There's not need to worry about concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sort of lock in JavaScript: when you are sending you AJAX-request (native XMLHttpRequest) you can set asynchronous property to false so browser window will be kind of "locked" for any interactions from a user until it recieves an answer from server for the ajax-request being sent.

follow [mozilla dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Well... I guess you could write a "lock" of sorts, if what you're saying is that multiple things each need to have exclusive use of the object, where those uses span multiple events.

Here's a proof of concept: https://github.com/chris-martin/lock.js